# Incorrect times in application on ubuntu server

Tags: apache, ubuntu

My application is online using ubuntu 14.04 / Apache2.  My `date` command shows the proper EST time, but the app is using UTC.  What am I missing that I need to change for my app to use the server time?

Comment: What programming language / framework is your app written in?

Comment: in PHP using Laravel

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php then.

In case of deadlinks, here's the gist of it:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
do_stuff_here();
?>
```